# Call getChildFragmentManager inside EBean class using AndroidAnnotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-annotations

I want to create a `@EBean` class with all functions related to show and hide `ProgressDialog` and `DialogFragment`. Ex: I need to show the `ErrorDialogFragment` inside a `Fragment`, so `getChildFragmentManager()` is needed in this below code:

```
ErrorDialogFragment.showDefaultDialog(getChildFragmentManager(),
                    "Device is disconected!");
```

Is there a way to call `getChildFragmentManager()` inside the `@EBean` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@EBean
public class YourBean {

  @RootContext
  FragmentActivity activity;

  public void showDialog() {
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager(). ...
  }
}
```

However make sure you only inject this bean to a `FragmentActivity`, because otherwise the `Activity` itself will not be injected into the bean.

Edit: You cannot inject the `FragmentManager` nor the `Fragment` to the bean with annotations. You have to create a setter method for that:

```
@EBean
public class YourBean {

  private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

  public void showDialog() {
    ErrorDialogFragment.showDefaultDialog(fragmentManager,
                "Device is disconected!");
  }

  public void setFragmentManager(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
  }
}
```

In your `Fragment`:

```
@AfterInject
void afterInject() {
  yourBean.setFragmentManager(getChildFragmentManager());
}
```

Comment: I know your way but I want to `inject` the `Bean` to my `BaseFragment` and show the `Dialog` inside `Fragment` not `FragmentActivity`. How to do that?